# Tensorflow error Invalid argument Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle, tpu

I am receiving an error when I train my Deep Learning network using TPU

The error is related to the below part of my code but I don't know how to solve it.

```
preprocessing.RandomCrop(28, 28)
```

**NB: the code is running fine if I use no accelerator or GPU but not on TPU**

I am using tensorflow 2.6.4 and kaggle TPU V3-8 for the training

You can find the notebook link that reproduce the error  [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/sticlaboratory/test-tf-distribute) on kaggle

Here is the code that reproduce the error:

```py
import math, re, os
import tensorflow as tf
print("Tensorflow version " + tf.__version__)
# from tensorflow.keras.utils import img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.image import extract_patches
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,  Dense, Embedding, LayerNormalization, Conv2D, concatenate, LeakyReLU, GlobalMaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing#, RandomFlip, RandomZoom, RandomRotation, Rescaling

from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential#, Input
import numpy as np
AUTO = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

try: # detect TPUs
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver.connect() # TPU detection
    strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)
except ValueError: # detect GPUs
    strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy() # for GPU or multi-GPU machines
    
print("Number of accelerators: ", strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)


image_shape =(224, 224,3) #128, 128(286, 286) (224, 224,3) 
# batch_size = 5
batch_size = 32 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
save_dir = "./"
path = "../input/urban-and-rural-photos/train/"
N_sample = 32 # number of samples per batch


trainAug = Sequential([
#   preprocessing.Rescaling(scale=1.0 / 255),
    preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
    preprocessing.RandomZoom(
        height_factor=(-0.05, -0.15),
        width_factor=(-0.05, -0.15)),
    preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.3)
])


def load_images(path, size=image_shape):
    data_list = list()
    # enumerate filenames in directory, assume all are images
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        # load and resize the image
        pixels = load_img(path + filename, target_size=size)
        # convert to numpy array
        pixels = img_to_array(pixels)
        # store
        data_list.append(pixels)

    datas = np.asarray(data_list)
    datas = datas.astype('float32') / 255.0
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(datas)
    # dataset = dataset.batch(128)
    #   dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024)
    return dataset

with strategy.scope():
    # load dataset (low light image)
    dataL_all = (load_images(path + '/rural/')
    #   .shuffle(batch_size * 100)
        .batch(batch_size)
        .cache()
        .map(lambda x: (trainAug(x)),
             num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    )

    # load dataset (normal light image)
    dataH_all =(
        load_images(path + '/urban/')
    #   .shuffle(batch_size * 100)
        .batch(batch_size)
        .cache()
        .map(lambda x: (trainAug(x)),
             num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    )
dataL_allD = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataL_all)
dataH_allD = strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(dataH_all)

with strategy.scope():
    discriminator_local = Sequential(
        [
            Input(shape=image_shape),
            preprocessing.RandomCrop(28, 28),
            Conv2D(8, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
            Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
            Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
            Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
            Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
            Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same"),
            LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2),
            GlobalMaxPooling2D(),
            Dense(1),
        ],
        name="local_discriminator",
    )
    discriminator_local.summary()

@tf.function
def train_steps(dataset):
    return discriminator_local(dataset[0])


EPOCHS = 2
STEPS = 3
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    total_loss = 0.0
    num_batches = 0
    for step, datasets in enumerate(zip(dataL_allD, dataH_allD)):
        loss_per_replica= strategy.run(train_steps, args=(datasets,)) #train_step(datasets)
        total_loss += strategy.reduce("SUM", loss_per_replica,axis=0)
        num_batches += 1
    average_train_loss = total_loss / num_batches
    print(f'Epoch :{epoch}   loss : {average_train_loss}')
```

And here is the stack trace of the error:

```
2022-12-25 12:21:26.814769: W tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/eager/remote_tensor_handle_data.cc:76] Unable to destroy remote tensor handles. If you are running a tf.function, it usually indicates some op in the graph gets an error: 9 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_6371}} Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function_6096887307567101759[] on XLA_TPU_JIT: StatelessRandomUniformInt (No registered 'StatelessRandomUniformInt' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}
     (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match) Requested Attributes: T=DT_INT32, Tseed=DT_INT64, dtype=DT_INT32, _device="/device:TPU_REPLICATED_CORE"){{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}One approach is to outside compile the unsupported ops to run on CPUs by enabling soft placement `tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)`. This has a potential performance penalty.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5]]
     [[cluster_tpu_function/control_after/_1/_279]]
  (1) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_6371}} Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function_6096887307567101759[] on XLA_TPU_JIT: StatelessRandomUniformInt (No registered 'StatelessRandomUniformInt' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}
     (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match) Requested Attributes: T=DT_INT32, Tseed=DT_INT64, dtype=DT_INT32, _device="/device:TPU_REPLICATED_CORE"){{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}One approach is to outside compile the unsupported ops to run on CPUs by enabling soft placement `tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)`. This has a potential performance penalty.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5/_153]]
  (2) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_6371}} Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function_6096887307567101759[] on XLA_TPU_JIT: StatelessRandomUniformInt (No registered 'StatelessRandomUniformInt' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}
     (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match) Requested Attributes: T=DT_INT32, Tseed=DT_INT64, dtype=DT_INT32, _device="/device:TPU_REPLICATED_CORE"){{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}One approach is to outside compile the unsupported ops to run on CPUs by enabling soft placement `tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)`. This has a potential performance penalty.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5/_167]]
  (3) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_6371}} Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function_6096887307567101759[] on XL ... [truncated]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_20/3910360392.py in <module>
      6     for step, datasets in enumerate(zip(dataL_allD, dataH_allD)):
      7         loss_per_replica= strategy.run(train_steps, args=(datasets,)) #train_step(datasets)
----> 8         total_loss += strategy.reduce("SUM", loss_per_replica,axis=0)
      9         num_batches += 1
     10     average_train_loss = total_loss / num_batches

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in reduce(self, reduce_op, value, axis)
   1386 
   1387           self._reduce_sum_fns[axis] = def_function.function(reduce_sum_fn)
-> 1388         value = self._reduce_sum_fns[axis](value)
   1389       else:
   1390         value = self.run(reduce_sum, args=(value,))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    860       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    861       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 862       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    863       if self._created_variables:
    864         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2939     with self._lock:
   2940       (graph_function,
-> 2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
   2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3312     if self.input_signature is None or args is not None or kwargs is not None:
   3313       args, kwargs, flat_args, filtered_flat_args = \
-> 3314           self._function_spec.canonicalize_function_inputs(*args, **kwargs)
   3315     else:
   3316       flat_args, filtered_flat_args = [None], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in canonicalize_function_inputs(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2695 
   2696     if self._input_signature is None:
-> 2697       inputs, flat_inputs, filtered_flat_inputs = _convert_numpy_inputs(inputs)
   2698       kwargs, flat_kwargs, filtered_flat_kwargs = _convert_numpy_inputs(kwargs)
   2699       return (inputs, kwargs, flat_inputs + flat_kwargs,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _convert_numpy_inputs(inputs)
   2735   # are eventually passed to ConcreteFunction()._call_flat, which requires
   2736   # expanded composites.
-> 2737   flat_inputs = nest.flatten(inputs, expand_composites=True)
   2738 
   2739   # Check for NumPy arrays in arguments and convert them to Tensors.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py in flatten(structure, expand_composites)
    339     return [None]
    340   expand_composites = bool(expand_composites)
--> 341   return _pywrap_utils.Flatten(structure, expand_composites)
    342 
    343 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/values.py in _type_spec(self)
    381       return copy.deepcopy(self._type_spec_override)
    382     return PerReplicaSpec(
--> 383         *(type_spec.type_spec_from_value(v) for v in self._values))
    384 
    385   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/values.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    381       return copy.deepcopy(self._type_spec_override)
    382     return PerReplicaSpec(
--> 383         *(type_spec.type_spec_from_value(v) for v in self._values))
    384 
    385   @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/type_spec.py in type_spec_from_value(value)
    537       is not supported.
    538   """
--> 539   spec = _type_spec_from_value(value)
    540   if spec is not None:
    541     return spec

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/type_spec.py in _type_spec_from_value(value)
    559   if isinstance(value, ops.Tensor):
    560     # Note: we do not include Tensor names when constructing TypeSpecs.
--> 561     return tensor_spec.TensorSpec(value.shape, value.dtype)
    562 
    563   if isinstance(value, composite_tensor.CompositeTensor):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in shape(self)
   1173         # `_tensor_shape` is declared and defined in the definition of
   1174         # `EagerTensor`, in C.
-> 1175         self._tensor_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(self._shape_tuple())
   1176       except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
   1177         six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)

InvalidArgumentError: 9 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_6371}} Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function_6096887307567101759[] on XLA_TPU_JIT: StatelessRandomUniformInt (No registered 'StatelessRandomUniformInt' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}
     (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match) Requested Attributes: T=DT_INT32, Tseed=DT_INT64, dtype=DT_INT32, _device="/device:TPU_REPLICATED_CORE"){{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}One approach is to outside compile the unsupported ops to run on CPUs by enabling soft placement `tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)`. This has a potential performance penalty.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5]]
     [[cluster_tpu_function/control_after/_1/_279]]
  (1) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_6371}} Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function_6096887307567101759[] on XLA_TPU_JIT: StatelessRandomUniformInt (No registered 'StatelessRandomUniformInt' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}
     (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match) Requested Attributes: T=DT_INT32, Tseed=DT_INT64, dtype=DT_INT32, _device="/device:TPU_REPLICATED_CORE"){{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}One approach is to outside compile the unsupported ops to run on CPUs by enabling soft placement `tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)`. This has a potential performance penalty.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5/_153]]
  (2) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_6371}} Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function_6096887307567101759[] on XLA_TPU_JIT: StatelessRandomUniformInt (No registered 'StatelessRandomUniformInt' OpKernel for XLA_TPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}
     (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match) Requested Attributes: T=DT_INT32, Tseed=DT_INT64, dtype=DT_INT32, _device="/device:TPU_REPLICATED_CORE"){{node local_discriminator/random_crop/stateless_random_uniform}}One approach is to outside compile the unsupported ops to run on CPUs by enabling soft placement `tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)`. This has a potential performance penalty.
    TPU compilation failed
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5]]
     [[tpu_compile_succeeded_assert/_9679846132704141549/_5/_167]]
  (3) Invalid argument: {{function_node __inference_tpu_function_6371}} Compilation failure: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph cluster_tpu_function_6096887307567101759[] on XL ... [truncated]
```

Please, I need your help to advance on my project

Comment: Your code example is incomplete. You removed exactly the lines that is causing the exception! You should check if `datasets` is what your `train_step` function expects it to be (again, no way for anyone here to help because you don't give the relevant code). You need to provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @suvayu, thank you for reminding me, I updated the question and add the code to reproduce the error. Please, help if you can on this issue.